# Why my delegate methods are not being called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I'm using CFViewController and I need that the delegate methods be called.

**CFCoverFlowView.h**

```
@class CFCoverFlowView;
@protocol CFCoverFlowViewDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)coverFlowView:(CFCoverFlowView *)coverFlowView didScrollPageItemToIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (void)coverFlowView:(CFCoverFlowView *)coverFlowView didSelectPageItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;

@end

@interface CFCoverFlowView : UIControl

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CFCoverFlowViewDelegate> delegate;
```

**CFViewController.h**

```
@class CFCoverFlowView;

@interface CFViewController : UIViewController <CFCoverFlowViewDelegate>{
    int contador;
    CFCoverFlowView *coverFlowView2;
}
```

**CFViewContorller.m**

```
- (void)coverFlowView:(CFCoverFlowView *)coverFlowView didScrollPageItemToIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSLog(@"didScrollPageItemToIndex >>> %@", @(index));

    self.pageControl.currentPage = index;

    contador++;
    if(contador == [computers count]){
        contador = 0;

    }
    pageControl2.currentPage = contador;
    NSLog(@"Scroll: %d", contador);

}

- (void)coverFlowView:(CFCoverFlowView *)coverFlowView didSelectPageItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSLog(@"didSelectPageItemAtIndex >>> %@", @(index));
}
```

I need that this two last functions be called when I scroll a page. Like when you have a `UITableView`and it calls this function `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` Can someone help me?
Thank you for advance.

Comment: When I scroll a page de delegate should called the function `didScrollPageItemToIndex` no? Like when you have a `UITableView`be called didYouSelectItem... no?

Comment: No. what is the difference with this? `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: Actually I think I've got the wrong end of the stick; sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line:

```
[coverFlowView2 setDelegate:self];
```

where you have initialized `coverFlowView2` in `CFViewController`.